# What are the differences between cancer and tumour?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer

What are the differences between cancer and tumour? I mean is it in the DNA or shape or something else... And how can a benign tumour turn into a malignant tumour? The body has a lot of tumours all the time, however not all of them become cancerous, why is this so?

So my main question is: What is so special about cancer cells that they can get out of control unlike an ordinary benign tumour?

Comment: please accept an answer. It is considered impolite when the question has been answered to the fullest and the OP (original poster) has not accepted an answer. It means that the OP is expecting something more. So if you feel that the question has been answered, then please accept the answer which has suited you.

Comment: What is the difference between "a car" and a "Volvo XC60"? What is difference between "disease" and "sarcoidosis"? What is the difference between "planet" and "Earth"?

Answer (score 19):

A **tumour** is simply a space-occupying lesion (something that should not be there, that is; a "lump") caused by abnormal cell replication.

(In medicine, the word "tumour" literally means "swelling", and can sometimes refer to that instead, but that's a different story).

**Cancer** is a disease in which cell replication is *totally out of control*. What causes cancer is damage to the genes (DNA) which normally *stop* cell replication when it needs to be stopped.

There's no such thing as an "ordinary tumour"; all tumours are abnormal. However, what makes a *benign* (harmless) tumour different from a *cancerous* tumour is that there is still some mechanisms stopping the cells inside the tumour from replicating; they are doing it more than they should, but they are not *totally* out of control. When those last mechanisms are broken too, the tumour is cancerous.

(This is a simplified explanation; the actual explanation is a semester-long university course. It's mostly accurate for the layman, though)

Comment: Thanks! and where can I get the "actual explanation"? can you give me an outer source for that?(book/site etc)

Comment: Wikipedia is always a good start; the article on cancer has a "Further Reading" section down near the bottom.

Comment: *Uterine smooth muscle tumors other than the [ordinary leiomyomas and leiomyosarcomas](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20179432): a review of selected variants with emphasis on recent advances and unusual morphology that may cause concern for malignancy.* ') Just nit picking here, but I do believe many kinds of "tumors" are so common that they deserve the appellation "ordinary". Subcutaneous lipomas, for instance.

Comment: Hallmarks of Cancer: The Next Generation is a review article that'll provide a great understanding, sorry for no link, on my phone.

Comment: @Kendall [here](http://www.cell.com/abstract/S0092-8674%2811%2900127-9) is the link to the 2011 Cell article by the same name. I could download the PDF at home, so I believe it's open-access.

Comment: @anongoodnurse You make a good point; I think it depends on your definition of "ordinary". All tumours are out-of-the-ordinary in one sense because they come about due to cellular dysfunction - cells doing what they would not ordinarily do. In another sense, though, I suppose some "ordinary" tumours do exist.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am confused about the title, does it imply that leiomyosarcomas are also ordinary? I agree that leiomyomas are ordinary as are lipomas

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr answer, tumors are **abnormal** growth (or swelling, thanks to Malic for pointing out) of any kind. The *kinds* of tumors are benign and malignant.

Benign tumors are usually slow growing and harmless. Example would be a lipoma.

Malignant tumors are otherwise called cancers. They generally have a bad prognosis. Very few cancers are *curable*.

Swelling over an injury (which is also called tumor) is due to local transudation (shift of plasma from capillaries). This is temporary and usually goes down one the injury heals.

Comment: All of the tumors are abnormal?  I heard that if part of the body get hurt, the body does a tumor on purpose to fix the part that get hurt, is it true? and there is a lot of small tumors in the body at a given moment?

Comment: When a part of body swells, it is also called tumor. Thanks for pointing out! @MalicOfSdom. But that swelling is also considered pathological. As it is a deviation from physiology

Comment: haa! so every time a part of the body swells it is tumor...scary! and does a benign tumor can turn to a malignant tumor?

Comment: Yes, it can occur. Some benign tumors are more prone to malignant change while some practically never do

Comment: In general, though tumor can denote any swelling regardless of the presence of any growth, practically speaking, doctors rarely use the term tumor to denote an edematous swelling. So for practical purposes, the word tumor means abnormal growth

Comment: ha ok, and when I get hurt for example in the bone, the swell on it is benign tumor?  what is the chance that it will convert to malignant tumor?

Comment: @MalicOfSdom Tumors due to swelling in response to injury will never turn malignant. Only benign tumors due to abnormal growth has the potential to turn malignant

Comment: and how this turn from benign to malignant obtained?  is it in the genome of the tumor or something else...?

Comment: @MalicOfSdom you should post this as a new question. There are many theories in that. Searching in wiki will be of great help too.

Comment: one more thing: malignant tumor always strarts from a benign tumor?

Comment: Not always, can start from normal cells too

Comment: @CRags - you've given a number of incorrect answers here. Curable cancers are *not* few and far between. Malignant tumors are not always deadly (see, for example, basal cell carcinomas). You should try to stay within provable statements when answering questions.

Comment: @CRags - no, I don't agree; if I did, I would not have left that comment. I define "cure" like any normal person: it's gone and will never bother you again. It is possible, and it is done every day, to declare a cancer patient cured. Childhood leukemia is now a largely curable disease; others include some lymphomas, cervical cancer, and others if caught early. Clearly there are some that, regardless the initial response, can still come back. I'm just saying, don't make claims which are untrue. BCC is a malignant cancer with a very good prognosis, if not even excellent.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I will be more careful @anongoodnurse Thanks for helping me answer better